# How can I assign a class to every nth div element in map, in react?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, jsx

How can I assign a class to every nth div element in map, in react ?
Here is my code:

```
const users = [{name: 'Max'}, 
               {name: 'Pete'}, 
               {name: 'Ben'}, 
               {name: 'Bruce'}];

return ({users.map(({name})=>{
  return (
    <div className="users">{name}</div>
);
)})
```

How can I assign a different class to every 2nd div element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use index inside [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) callback function to get current index.

```
return ({users.map(({name},index)=>{
  if(index%2==1){
   return (
    <div className="users">{name}</div>
); 
  }
   return (
    <div>{name}</div>
);
});});
```

Comment: Glad. Please mark it as the accepted answer, if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to do this via the second parameter in the `map` callback, as per @TusharShahi's answer, you may not need to do this at all. Using the [`:nth-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) CSS selector, you can just apply the same class to all elements and use CSS to mark every `n`th element:

Make every 5th element red:

```
.users:nth-child(5n){
    color:red;
}
```

Make every even element blue:

```
.users:nth-child(even){
    color:blue;
}
```

See runnable code below:

```css
.users:nth-child(5n) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="users">user</div>
<div class="users">user</div>
<div class="users">user</div>
<div class="users">user</div>
<div class="users">user</div>
<div class="users">user</div>
<div class="users">user</div>
<div class="users">user</div>
<div class="users">user</div>
<div class="users">user</div>
<div class="users">user</div>
<div class="users">user</div>
<div class="users">user</div>
<div class="users">user</div>
<div class="users">user</div>
<div class="users">user</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your needs, you might also achieve this only with CSS, using the :nth-child pseudo-class:

```css
div {color:blue;}
div:nth-child(even){color:red;}
```

```html
<div>Max</div>
<div>Pete</div>
<div>Ben</div>
<div>Bruce</div>
```

if your HTML is becoming more complex, and you need to style children nodes under this div, this is probably NOT the best option, and giving a class makes sense, but I thought it was worth mentioning.